# Save spreadsheet ID to model using Drive Picker

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to use the Driver Picker widget to select a spreadsheet and save the file ID of the spreadsheet to a data model.

I have the selectedDocUrl field of the Drive Picker set to the fileID column in my model (`@datasource.item.fileID`) but as expected this saves the entire URL of the file to the model.

I am looking to capture the file ID only.

**Full URL:**
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q4z5ZsE5eDm14MysAdb-CnApSNlzToMdXTTCgrN6BNA/edit`

**File ID:**
`1Q4z5ZsE5eDm14MysAdb-CnApSNlzToMdXTTCgrN6BNA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **onDocumentSelect** event handler of the drive picker and do the following:

```
widget.datasource.item.fileID = result.docs[0].id;
```

Keep in mind that the above will work if the datasource is properly binded.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!